# Function that takes in optional parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameter-passing

From the below code after submitting it as a coding test challenge. I used to get the following feedback from a robot or a bot that is marking the challenge that task() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name' but if I do run it on vs code it will print Hello Friend! And I don't know why. Please Clarify.

```
def task(name):
    
    print("Hello", name + "!") 
task("Friend")
```

Comment: How are you calling `task` in the online version? This code won't cause that error.

Comment: Presumably the challenge tests are calling `task()` with no argument - does the challenge description say what the behavior is supposed to be?

Comment: `name` is not defined as an optional parameter.  To make a parameter optional you need to provide a default value, like `def task(name="Ahmad"):`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they test `task()` without an argument for `name`. Try to set a default value like this

```
def task(name=""):
    print("Hello", name + "!") 
task("Friend")  # Hello Friend!
task()  # Hello !
```